# How to generate items in a list under specific keeps

Tags: list, specman

I want to generate items in a list under specific restrictions. For example:

```
  dup_offset: list of uint(bits:5);
  keep dup_offset.size() == 3;

  foo_gen() is { 
     for each in dup_offset {
        gen dup_offset[index] keeping {
            read_only(index == 0) => it <= 21;
            read_only(index == 1) => it < dup_offset[0];
            read_only(index == 2) => it < dup_offset[0];
            read_only(index == 2) => it < dup_offset[1];
        };
     };
  };
```

The list is a global variable, and the generation is done in a gen_foo().
It doesn't compile in the way i wrote it. 
Can anyone suggest how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'gen keeping' construct cannot be used on list items.
you can still model your constraints using the keyword 'prev'.
If I understand correctly, you wish that all your items have a value which is smaller or equal to 21, and that each item will be smaller than the previous items.

```
  !dup_offset: list of uint(bits:5);

  foo_gen() is { 
     gen dup_offset keeping {
         it.size() == 3;
         for each in it {
             it <= 21; //all items will be <= 21
             (prev == 0 ? (it == 0) : (it < prev)); // each items is smaller than the previous item
         };
     };
  };
```

Comment: What if `dup_offset[0]` generated to be 0? Then the others will fail because they have constraint on `it < prev;`. I need the others to be also 0 in such a case.

Comment: see edit constraint. first, i added a necessary 'for each' constraint. second, i used the ternary construct to express that if 'item == 0' it means the rest of the items are also 0

Answer (score 0):

Using your constraints as they were written, your code can be rewritten as:

```
!dup_offset: list of uint(bits:5);
keep dup_offset.size() == 3;
keep for each in dup_offset {
    index == 0 => it <= 21;
    index == 1 => it < prev;
    index == 2 => it < dup_offset[0];
    index == 2 => it < prev;
};    

foo_gen() is { 
    gen dup_offset;
};
```

Note that you can remove the third constraint in the `keep for each`, since it is immediately implied from the combination of the second and fourth ones.

However, if I understand your requirement correctly - you need a decreasing series of elements smaller than 21 - then the constraints can be rewritten as follows:

```
!dup_offset: list of uint(bits:5);
keep dup_offset.size() == 3;
keep for each (a) using index (ind1) in dup_offset {
    ind1 == 0 => a <= 21;
    for each (b) using index (ind2) in dup_offset {
        ind1 > ind2 => a < b;
    };
};


foo_gen() is { 
    gen dup_offset;
};
```

Note that now the model no longer depends on the size of list - making the list larger will not require adding any more constraints.